# Using PHP, AJAX and MySQL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to web development, and currently using codeigniter php framework. What I'm currently stuck on at the moment is, I have a page which contains a select dropdown, it has values id 1, 2, 3 etc grabbed from the database. Now what I to do is, when a value is selected from the drop down, lets say "2", it will show the information of the columns which has id 2, the id are unique. So if I changed it to id=3, then it would show information regarding that one.

the query would be, but with a dynamic id:

`select name, address, age from user where id= 2`

What I have currently is this for **view**, in one php file as v_services.php :

```
<script>
        function showSpecs(str){
          if (str ==""){
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
          }else{
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
              xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{
              xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                document.getElementId("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
              }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?echo base_url();?>user/v_services.php?q="+str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
          }
        }
      </script>

<?php
                $q = intval($_GET['q']);

                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_test");
                if (!$con){
                  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                }

                mysqli_select_db($con,"db_test");
                $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                echo "<table>
                <tr>
                <th>Processor</th>
                <th>RAM</th>
                <th>Harddisk</th>
                <th>Graphics Card</th>
                <th>Monitor</th>
                </tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['NAME'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['ADDRESS'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['AGE'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But it gives me an error `Message: Undefined index: q`. So please if you have experience in PHP, AJAX, MYSQL it would be much appreciated to help.

Thank you.

p.s. the resource for the above code I got from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)
p.s.s my database connection is already correct. It just implementing the code that I have problems with.

Here is how whats happening in the select tags

```
   <?php echo form_open('Services/create');?>
    ID: <br>
    <select name="id" onchange="showSpecs(this.value)">

      <?php
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_test");
        $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from user");
          while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
              if ($row['status']=== "1")
                  echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">' . $row['ID'] . "</option>";        
          }
      ?>
      </select> <br>
      Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <br>
      Email:<br>
      <input type="text" name="email"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create reservation">
      <?php echo validation_errors();?>
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you using Codeigniter? Why are you using <?php echo base_url();?>user/v_services.php?q which has a .php on the end... What is the actual controller/method you are attempting to call?

Comment: Sorry mate, I just started learning codeigniter. I recently found the resource I needed on the w3site provided, but have trouble to implement it to MVC style, therefore I put it in one view file.

Comment: Fair enough - we all have to start somewhere. here is a tip... As you are rendering the js on the page, you could go and look at the URL being used. Just do a simple View Source from your browser and go looking for it and see what it looks like.

Comment: An advice, avoid using AJAX XHR, use JQuery Ajax, it's easy and more flexible

Comment: @Marwan I Totally agree but let's get this bit working first before throwing in extra bits for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in `xmlhttp.open()`

You want to use `<?=base_url();?>` instead of `<?echo base_url();?>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry brother, it's still undefined :/

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are still learning and using example code and porting it over to CI. So on that note I am not going to go into how to use the Database class etc and stick with what you have for now...

Your main problem is this line

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?echo base_url();?>user/v_services.php?q="+str, true);
```

I'll assume that the controller/method should be **user/v_services** where **user** is the controller and v_services is the method (function) in the **`user`** controller that contains your PHP Code.

If it's not - change it to suit what you have..

So on that basis the code above would become...

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo base_url();?>user/v_services?q="+str, true);
```

NOTE:

1. The .php is Not required in the URL due to the nature of urls in frameworks such as CI in this case.

I performed a quick "knockup" of the same tutorial you referred to and it "works".

There are other ways to do this which is for another day.

See if that gets you somewhere further along...

**UPDATE:**

Just for some clarification...

Your View Code should be handled by a method. Let's call it **services**. So in your controller **user**

```
public function services {
    $this->load->view('v_services'); // This is your View
}
```

Next we need a method that will handle the response to your AJAX code.
So your PHP Code would go in its own method we could call services_ajax.

```
public function services_ajax(){

// Your PHP Code goes in here

}
```

NOTE: IMPORTANT! As we have changed the name of the method handling the AJAX Call...

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo base_url();?>user/v_services?q="+str, true);
```

NOW becomes

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo base_url();?>user/services_ajax?q="+str, true);
```

The change is the URL **user/services_ajax**

Does that make sense? You need a method to deal with displaying the view and another method for processing the javascript/ AJAX request.

Then you have to ensure that all the URLS are correct.

Comment: Hello sir,
Do you mind sharing the code you tried? It would be great help!

Comment: Did you try the suggestion I made above?

Comment: I'm on that now.

Comment: Hello sir,
I tried it, but it still doesn't work. Most of which are undefined index, variables etc. It would be big help if you shared your working out. Thank you :)

Comment: So you are still getting the undefined index 'q' message or new ones?

Comment: Undefined 'q'. I'm still not confident regarding my MVC structure, it might be that. So it would be big reference if I had an example using the MVC.

Comment: Ahh ok... Well you should have a method/function that performs the actual display of your "View" code... The PHP part should be in a different method as it's only called via your javascript (AJAX) call so all it needs to do is to return a value...

Comment: What I have done so far is:
1. I put the AJAX script in the view file, and called the controller index function to view the file but also call the model method.
2. In the model method it has a paramater to be passed, which is 'q' and searched the database where id='q'. It then returns the result.
3. Back to the controller index method, it save the return value in an array, and pass that array to the view function.
4. In the view file, it tries to print each value in the array but cannot do so.

The errors are:
1. Message: Undefined variable: q - (when i try to pass it to model method)

Comment: @user478905 ok I have attempted to explain what you need to do and think about. Let me know if that makes sense.